# In JUnit, How to skip the rest of test methods in current step and continue on next step?

Tags: java, junit

assuming I have Scenario.java:

```
@runwith(Suite.Class)
@SuiteClasses({
step1.class, step2.class
})
```

step1.class includes multiple tests methods,

```
public step1 {
@test
testmethod1(){
...
}

@test
testmethod2(){
...
}

@test
testmethod3(){
...
}

...
}
```

And if I get any failure or errors in testmethodX, I want to just skip all rest test methods in this step class but continue on with the next step.

Is it implementable?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to achieve that kind of manipulation of JUnit is with TestRules (`@Rule` and `@ClassRule`), and then I am not sure you will be able to get it to skip the rest of the class.

I would question why you want to skip the rest of the tests, they might actually provide valuable feedback as to why the first test failed; had exactly this today, the test failed, as did the others but the way in which the others failed suggested to me the fix to make them pass.

[Possible inspiration](http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/)